# Como deixar um background responsivo em c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, aplicação-desktop

Como relacionar o background_image ao tamanho da janela?

Exemplo:
    Define minha imagem de fundo, mas ao alterar o tamanho da janela(minimizando) a imagem fica "incompleta", e não segue as bordas agindo tanto que independente.

Comment: Você está programando para web ou desktop?

Comment: Para o Desktop usando WinForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Form tem uma propriedade `BackgroundImageLayout` veja qual se adéqua a sua situação. Imagino que sera `Stretch`